# How add expressions in after effects to layer or composition using Extendscript and javascript?

Tags: javascript, expression, extendscript, after-effects

Can anybody help me?
I am trying to write a script for after effects CC using Extendscript.
I want add expression to layer in the javascript.
I wrote this code here

var MyTime = app.project.item(1).layer(1);
 var Mytime2 = MyTime.timeRemapEnabled = true;

and i want add exspression to layer(1), 
 loopOut('Cycle')

How can i do it?
Is it possible?
Thanks.

Comment: I have worked here it:
 var code = "loopOut('Cycle')";

   app.project.item(1).layer(1).timeRemapEnabled = true; 

   app.project.item(1).layer(1).timeRemap.expression =code;


Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

To add an expression to a layers attribute you do something like this:

```
layer.transform.position.expression = 'loopOut("Cycle")';
```

Comment: I have worked here it:
 var code = "loopOut('Cycle')";
   app.project.item(1).layer(1).timeRemapEnabled = true; 
   app.project.item(1).layer(1).timeRemap.expression =code;

Thanks.

Comment: Do you know how to change the duration of the layer in the composition?

Comment: You should try somethings out. Take a look at the [After Effects Scripting guide ](http://blogs.adobe.com/wp-content/blogs.dir/48/files/2012/06/After-Effects-CS6-Scripting-Guide.pdf?file=2012/06/After-Effects-CS6-Scripting-Guide.pdf). There are also a lot of scripts out there that already do that. If you then still are stuck - ask a new question here on sto